# Scala Function Literals Type issue

Tags: scala, currying

Why `executeCommand` is accepting the `callBack` function of wrong return type?

```
import scala.sys.process._

object Test {

  def executeCommand(x: String)(y: Int => Unit) = {
    def matchStrToInt(str: String) = {
      str match {
        case "true"  => 1
        case "false" => 2
      }
    }
    y(matchStrToInt(x))
  }                                     //> executeCommand: (x: String)(y: Int => Unit)Unit

  executeCommand("true")(callBack)

  def callBack(x: Int): Int = {
    x
  }                                     //> callBack: (x: Int)Int

}
```

As far as I know Scala is strictly statically typed language.
Can someone explain the reason behind it?

Comment: you can minimize this example to something a lot simpler: `def callBack(x: Int): Int = x;  def executeCommand(y: Int => Unit) = 5; executeCommand(callBack)` - would be helpful, there's a lot here that isn't relevant to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what is happening here is that two separate mechanisms in the Scala compiler are working together:

- [Value discarding](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-discarding)
- [Eta expansion](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion)

### Value discarding

This is basically just a way to avoid having to explicitly write `()`, the `Unit` value, every time `Unit` is the expected type. Like at the end of a `while` loop, a `Unit` returning method, a `for(a <- list){ ... }` expression, etc.

It rewrites (in memory during compilation, not on disk) code like this

```
def foo: Unit = 42
```

to this

```
def foo: Unit = { 42; () }
```

### Eta expansion

This is how **methods** in Scala are converted to **functions**. A method is a JVM construct, an element of a JVM classfile. A function is just a value, an instance of a `scala.FunctionN` class. You can pass around functions as values (because they are values), but you can't pass around methods as values (because they're not).

So basically the compiler does the following transformation:

```
def foo(i: Int): Int = i
def bar(f: Int => Int) = f

bar(foo)
 ~~~>
bar( (x1: Int) => foo(x1) )
```

### Bring the two together

So when you have this code:

```
def foo(i: Int): Int = i
def bar(f: Int => Unit) = f

bar(foo)
```

The compiler will first use eta expansion to convert `foo` to a function.

```
bar( (x1: Int) => foo(x1) )
```

And then it will see that `foo(x1)` is an expression of type `Int` while an expression of type `Unit` is expected there. So it will apply value discarding.

```
bar( (x1: Int) => { foo(x1); () } )
```

You can check that this "problem" only occurs when converting methods to functions:

```
scala> def bar(f: Int => Unit) = f
bar: (f: Int => Unit)Int => Unit

scala> val foo = (i: Int) => i
foo: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> bar(foo)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Int
 required: Int => Unit
       bar(foo)
           ^
```

Comment: +1, but I would also mention that this behaviour of scala is still inconsistent: `xx(zz _)` works, but `val a = zz _; xx(a)` doesn't

Comment: I agree. I'm not so sure it is desired behaviour either. Although I don't think it is considered a bug by the Scala maintainers.